# Maximum Number of line items on a bill import to QuickBooks Online

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

In v2 how can I find the maximum number of lines that QBO will allow on a transaction add.  Specifically I am looking for the maximum number of lines (they are using items) that can be included on vendor bill add.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the exact number, but we definitely support more than 2,000 lines. I'll update this post if I get the exact number.

Thanks

Comment: Karen, what is the max number that you have seen? just out of curiosity